# Не могу поставить g++ на ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, g++, apt-get

Вот ошибка:

```
root@vm21575:~/sandbox/gitcloner# apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-4.6 (>= 4.6.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**UPD**

```
root@vm21575:~# apt-cache policy g++ g++-4.6
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
     4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
g++-4.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
     4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
root@vm21575:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
root@vm21575:~#
```

**UPD**

```
root@vm21575:~# aptitude -f install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

root@vm21575:~# aptitude install g++
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++ g++-4.6{a} libc6-dev{ab} libstdc++6-4.6-dev{a}
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 44.1 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 is installed.
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.15) but it is not going to be installed.
             Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     g++ [Not Installed]
2)     g++-4.6 [Not Installed]
3)     libc6-dev [Not Installed]
4)     libstdc++6-4.6-dev [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

**UPD**

```
root@vm21575:~# apt-cache policy libc6-dev
libc6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.15-0ubuntu10.15
  Version table:
     2.15-0ubuntu10.15 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main i386 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/izx/ovz-libc/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages



root@vm21575:~# aptitude install g++
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++ g++-4.6{a} libc6-dev{ab} libstdc++6-4.6-dev{a}
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 44.1 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 is installed.
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.15) but it is not going to be installed.
             Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     g++ [Not Installed]
2)     g++-4.6 [Not Installed]
3)     libc6-dev [Not Installed]
4)     libstdc++6-4.6-dev [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
2)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-105.146 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
3)     manpages [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
4)     manpages-dev [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
5)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (pre
6)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precis



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
2)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-23.36 (precise)]
3)     manpages [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
4)     manpages-dev [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
5)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (pre
6)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precis



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
2)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-105.146 (precise-security, precise-updates)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
3)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (pre
4)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precis

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
5)     libc-dev-bin recommends manpages-dev


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
2)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-23.36 (precise)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
3)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (pre
4)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precis

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
5)     libc-dev-bin recommends manpages-dev


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (precise)]
2)     libc6-dev [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (precise)]
3)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-105.146 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
4)     manpages [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
5)     manpages-dev [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
```

Comment: список пакетов перед этим обновляли? `apt-get update`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, естественно. А также `apt-get upgrade` и `apt-get dist-upgrade` делал.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154402/install-gcc-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: приложите ещё, пожалуйста, вывод `apt-mark showhold`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, на запрос `apt-mark showhold` нет вывода.

Comment: возможно, резолвер apt-get-а не справляется по каким-то (пока непонятным) причинам. попробуйте воспользоваться резолвером aptitude-а. сначала дозакончить установки: `aptitude -f install`, а затем устанавливать пакет: `aptitude install g++`. если что-то «пойдёт не так», приложите полный вывод этих команд.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово.

Comment: openvz? это у вас виртуальная машина? если да, проконсультируйтесь сначала с её администратором(-ами). // хотя, возможно, что-то полезное можно будет подсказать по результатам вывода `apt-cache policy libc6-dev`

Comment: кстати, при ответе `n` (no) на вопрос *Accept this solution?* резолвер aptitude-а может предложить и более разумные варианты. покажите, пожалуйста, пару-тройку его других предложений: отвечайте `n` пару-тройку раз, а затем ответьте `q` и дополните приложенный вывод другими предложениями от резолвера.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово. После ответа `n` появляется список. Следует ли из него что-нибудь выбирать?

Comment: это список предлагаемых действий: что поставить, что удалить, что обновить. согласиться с предложенным вариантом действий можно, нажав `y` (и `enter`). я думаю, как раз последний из тех вариантов, которые вы опубликовали, больше всего и подойдёт в вашем случае. тот, где предлагается поставить openvz-шные версии пакетов, ведь, как я понял, от администраторов вы по поводу этого openvz-шного барахла ответа не получили.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я и не спрашивал. А вариант собрать `g++` из исходников сработал бы в этом случае? Стоит пробовать?

Comment: пакет *g++* — это мета-пакет (фактически, полезного в нём — только прописанные зависимости). пакет *g++-4.6* — это часть [*gcc*](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (gnu compiler **collection**). // **пере**собрать всю коллекцию (или её часть), конечно, никто не может запретить. только зачем пересобирать? у вас так и не получилось «разрулить» зависимости, поломанными кривыми пакетами из этого «левого» openvz-шного репозитория?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как выяснилось, основная проблема в том, что у вас установлены пакеты из стороннего репозитория, связанного с *openvz*.

вероятно, у вас виртуальная машина, работающая как раз под управлением *openvz*, и замена этих пакетов дистрибутивными может привести, например, к её неработоспособности (тут надо уточнять у администратора(-ов) сервера).

разрешитель зависимостей программы *apt-get* не смог справиться с данным выбором.

я предлагаю воспользоваться (хотя бы для данного случая) программой *aptitude*, обладающей значительно более «интеллектуальным» разрешителем зависимостей, который может составить несколько вариантов требуемых действий, и предложить их вам на выбор.

пример такого предложения:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
2)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-105.146 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
3)     manpages [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
4)     manpages-dev [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
5)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (pre
6)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (now, precise) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 (precis

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

с ним можно согласиться (действие по умолчанию), не согласиться, введя `n` (будет рассчитан и предложен другой вариант действий), либо закончить работу программы, нажав `q`.

---

в вашем конкретном случае, вероятно, имеет смысл согласиться с вариантом, в котором предлагается установить пакеты из того же, связанного с *openvz*, репозитория:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (precise)]
2)     libc6-dev [2.15-0ubuntu10+openvz0 (precise)]
3)     linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-105.146 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
4)     manpages [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
5)     manpages-dev [3.35-0.1ubuntu1 (precise)]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Узнал много нового.